# C# - how to make a sequence of method calls atomic?

Tags: c#, atomic

I have to make a sequence of method calls in C# such that, if one of them fails, the subsequent methods should not be called. In short, the set of calls should be made atomic. How do I achieve this in C#?

Comment: that is not really the definition of atomic, what you are describing (subsequent methods after failing one not being called) can be done easily using try..catch construct.

Comment: Is this related to concurrency and multithreading or not? And should you rollback previous two methods if the third one failed?

Comment: @David would have agreed with you in general...but the specific problem at hand is such that my description holds good

Comment: @Sergey Teplyakov it is not related to concurrency or multithreading..rollback for previous methods not needed

Comment: Since there is confusion, is rolling back of any changes prior to the failing method call required?

Comment: @Aadith your description is fine *other than the word "atomic"*, which is misleading and used incorrectly here.  Atomic means that either all operations complete or none do.  You want to do nearly the opposite of that, which is execute until one fails then stop.

Comment: Hope this clarifies all the confusion - the requirement is to implement move operation for a distributed computing environment, whose API does not provide a way to move files. I am trying to call copy method and then delete method. such a 'move' operation has to be 'atomic'

Comment: No, it's only atomic if you guarantee that either the copy will not be made, or the copy and the delete will both happen. If that's not what you need, then atomicity has nothing to do with it. That said, if rollback isn't needed, I don't see the issue; just do the copy before the delete and don't trap the exception if the copy fails.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confusing the word "atomic" with something else. Atomic is when an operation cannot be interrupted and is usually done in multi threaded scenarios to protect shared resources.

What you want is normal control flow logic and the solution depends on what your methods looks like.

One solution could be to have them return a boolean indicating whether or not it succeeded:

```
bool success = false;

success = MethodA();
if (!success)
  return;
success = MethodB();
if (!success)
  return;

// or even like this as suggested in another answer
if (MethodA() &&
    MethodB() &&
    MethodC())
{
  Console.WriteLine("All succeeded");
}
```

You could also use exceptions and wrap all your method calls inside a try-catch block. If one of them fails (throws an exception), your catch block will execute and nothing after that method call in the try-block will get a chance to run.

```
try
{
  MethodA();
  MethodB();
  MethodC();
}
catch (MyMethodFailedException)
{
  // do something clever
}
```

If you need rollback functionality, you have to get into transactions but that's a whole bigger topic.

Answer (score 4):

TransactionScope might be what you need  see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx)

```
void RootMethod()
{
     using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
          /* Perform transactional work here */
          SomeMethod();
          SomeMethod2();
          SomeMethod3();
          scope.Complete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Note that he's specifying that rollback is *not* required - he wants to stop calling methods if one fails.  In fact, I think the word "atomic" is used here incorrectly.

Comment: as far as I know, and some quick testing confirms, this does not make the method calls atomic, in fact the transaction scope here does nothing unless you are creating an object in one of those methods that makes use of the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, get them to **throw an exception** when they fail and write your call sequence in a `try`/`catch` block.

If you can't do that for some reason, get them to return true on success and **use `&&`**:

```
if (a() && b() && c())
{
    ....
```

(That's not "atomic" in the true sense of the word, but I don't think you're asking for true atomicity.)

Comment: But then they would all have to be a defined as a `bool` method, wouldn't they? then they couldn't return anything else, and thus the exception route is better.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: Absolutely the exception route is better.

Comment: agreed..but i remember having read somewhere that C# provides something specifically to handle such a situation..looking for that way

Answer (score 1):

> if one of them fails, the subsequent methods should not be called. In short, the set of calls should be made atomic.

That is not what atomic means. As other answers have explained you can achieve this simply by checking the result of each method call and stopping when you get a certain result.

Atomic means that either all of the methods are called or none of them are. So you guarantee that the entire block runs or doesn't run at all. This is not something you can achieve in C# code, or in most languages that I'm aware of.

What you would have to do is separate checking results from final processing and queue up the final processing instead.

So instead of:

```
bool Method1() {
   if (CheckCondition)
      return false;
   DoSomethingImportant();
   return true;
}

bool Method2() {
   if (CheckCondition)
      return false;
   DoSomethingElseImportant();
   return true;
}

...

var success1 = Method1();
if (!success1)
   return;

var success2 = Method2();
if (!success2)
   return; // oops we already did something important in method1
```

Do something like:

```
bool Method1() {
   if (CheckCondition)
      return false;
   queue.Enqueue(DoSomethingImportant);
   return true;
}

bool Method2() {
   if (CheckCondition)
      return false;
   queue.Enqueue(DoSomethingElseImportant);
   return true;
}

...

var success1 = Method1();
if (!success1)
   return;

var success2 = Method2();
if (!success2)
   return; // no problem, nothing important has been invoked yet

// ok now we're completely successful, so now we can perform our important actions

while (queue.Any()) {
   var doSomethingImportant = queue.Dequeue();
   doSomethingImportant();
}
```

This still isn't anywhere's close to being actually "atomic", but it does give you a very basic "all or nothing" effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not catching exceptions, then if you throw an exception, all other methods called abort until a `try` block is found. So simply throw an exception where you need to have the atomic calls end (e.g. when it fails) and then catch it when you need to return to normal rutine.

Comment: agreed..but i remember having read somewhere that C# provides something specifically to handle such a situation..looking for that way

Comment: @Aadith. Handle what situation? When people demonstrate how to supply atomicity you complain that this isn't what you want, and when people demonstrate how to just abort early you talk of "such a situation".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough example of emulating a move operation with compensation if things go wrong. With exceptions thrown from your device copy methods on failure

```
string source = @"C:\file.txt", dest = @"D:\file.txt";

bool fileCopied = false;
try
{
    DeviceCopy(source, dest);
    fileCopied = true;
    DeviceDelete(source);
}
catch
{
    if (fileCopied)
    {
        DeviceDelete(dest);
    }
    throw;
}
```

Or with error codes e.g. could be bool for failed or check an integer

```
if (DeviceCopy(source, dest))
{
    if (!DeviceDelete(source))
    {
        if (!DeviceDelete(dest))
        {
            throw new IOException("Oh noes");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of multicast delegates?  Something like:

```
delegate void SomeFunc(int x);

void foo() {
    SomeFunc funcSeq = new SomeFunc(func1);
    funcSeq += new SomeFunc(func2);
    funcSeq(100);   // Invokes func1 and func2
}

void func1(int foo) {
    // Use foo
}

void func2(int bar) {
    // Use bar
}
```

This won't work, because the order that the functions is called in is undefined.  Plus, since your delegate functions can't return a value, there's no way to indicate that they failed, except by throwing an exception.  And if you're going to throw an exception, you're better off using one of the earlier suggestions, as then your order of execution is defined (and your methods don't all have to have the same signature).